# Annoying magnifying glass color after texstudio update

Tags: pdf, texstudio, viewers, magnification

I have just updated texstudio to version 4.4.1 and after the update the magnifying glass changed its color:
[image: New magnifier]

It can not be seen clearly from the picture, but the magnifier is white and indistinguishable from the paper, while the glass part is grey and annoying. How can I fix that?

Comment: I cannot see clearly from the picture, so I am not sure if I understand what your issue is. You have the issue when you press the mouse button to get the magnification or before that, when the small magnifier is seen at the screen, and nothing is magnified yet. Any way, as a first attempt to fix it go to Options->Configure TeXstudio->Internal PDF Viewer and be sure that: (1) Magnifier Shape is Circle, (2) Magnifier Size is 300px, and (3) Border is ticked.

Comment: @miltos The issue is that the colour of the mouse pointer is now different. It used to be dark instead of light gray. (however this might be better suited for the texstudio issue tracker at github than as a question here...)

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz. Yes, I agree with you. And IMO it's better looking as gray it is now, than the old black one!

Comment: @miltos I loved the old black one :) I have a lot or difficulties seeing the white one on a white background.

Comment: @Barbab If compiling your own texstudio version from source is an option: edit the file `./images-ng/modern/magnifier.svgz` e.g. which inkscape and choose whatever colour you like. Personally I'm using a 50% gray tone - this makes the magnifier nicely visible on light as well as on dark backgrounds.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think I am not able to do that, but I try. I loved the old black one too and I experience your same difficulties.

Comment: @Barbab It might be worth asking at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio Maybe they can add some option or something so users can configure the mouse pointer.